# Github Actions Matrix: Use variable inside "Matrix - include:"

Tags: github, github-actions

My workflow:

```
  publish:
    name:  Publish for ${{ matrix.os_identifier }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        include:
          - os: ubuntu-latest
            os_identifier: linux-x64
            publish_folder: "SpeciesDatabaseCmd_linux-x64_${{ github.ref_name }}"
            artifact_name: "SpeciesDatabaseCmd_linux-x64_${{ github.ref_name }}.zip"

          - os: windows-latest
            os_identifier: win-x64  
            publish_folder: "SpeciesDatabaseCmd_win-x64_${{ github.ref_name }}"
            artifact_name: "SpeciesDatabaseCmd_win-x64_${{ github.ref_name }}.zip"

          - os: macos-latest
            os_identifier: osx-x64
            publish_folder: "SpeciesDatabaseCmd_osx-x64_${{ github.ref_name }}"
            artifact_name: "SpeciesDatabaseCmd_osx-x64_${{ github.ref_name }}.zip"

          - os: macos-latest
            os_identifier: osx-arm64
            publish_folder: "SpeciesDatabaseCmd_osx-arm64_${{ github.ref_name }}"
            artifact_name: "SpeciesDatabaseCmd_osx-arm64_${{ github.ref_name }}.zip"
```

I would like to simplify and instead of repeat strings, I would like to do something like:

```
          - os: macos-latest
            os_identifier: osx-arm64
            publish_folder: "SpeciesDatabaseCmd_$os_identifier_${{ github.ref_name }}"
            artifact_name: "$publish_folder.zip"
```

But it fails...
I also tried using env which turns in a better simplification, but also fails:

```
  publish:
    name:  Publish for ${{ matrix.os_identifier }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    env:
       publish_folder: "SpeciesDatabaseCmd_${{ matrix.os_identifier }}_${{ github.ref_name }}"
       artifact_name: "$publish_folder.zip"
    strategy:
       matrix:
          ...
```

How can I achieve the wanted level of simplification?